# Fix for Sorry, Ubuntu 18.04 has experienced an internal error (nautilus)

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus

I have dual booted my laptop with ubuntu and windows. It was running fine a days back. However, recently everytime I start ubuntu, I am greeted with a "Ubuntu 18.04 has experienced an internal error" error. On clicking show details, I get the following as attached:

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vPbJ.png) [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGA13.png) [third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZUAB.png)

Is there any way this can be solved? I have a hunch there's some error with nautilus.

Comment: So send a report and forget it.

Comment: As @Pilot6 says .. if you send a report the nautilus developers might fix the problem and release an update. Also, if you tick off "Remember this in the future" You wont be bothered with this specific error again.

Comment: I already sent the report. Thanks! Hopefully it gets fixed.